# is facebook id immutable

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the offical **php facebook sdk** and I am pulling data about the current logged user by doing a simple:

```
$data = $fb->api('/me', 'GET');
```

now, `$data` contains a whole lot of stuff among which there is, as you might well know an id (`$data["id"]`). My question is: given a certain user, how unique and immutable do you reckon this piece of information is? Do you think it can change over time?

Comment: I belive it wont change as it is a unique id and its stores lot of information.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unique and won't change (according to the whole of FB API docs, but it is not explicitly said).

Answer (score 0):

The id won't change. However the associated access token will change frequently, so you should only store the id and use it to grab an access token when required.